# sendEmail script in Google Sheets is sending all rows vs sending just last row, and is not automated

Tags: google-apps-script

VERY new to coding. I have a sendEmail script in place to send an email to someone who has been assigned a new request. What I'd like it to do, is send an email when the last row is populated based on a query feed from another sheet. Right now, it's working, but it's sending all the rows in the sheet each time a new row is added vs just the last row of new information. I would also like to automate the email send when the new row is added vs having to click it each time.

Here is the script I'm using:

```
function sendEmail() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
var subject = sheet2.getRange(2,1).getValue();
var n=sheet1.getLastRow();
for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,2).getValue();
var Name=sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();
var Title=sheet1.getRange(i,3).getValue();
var Level=sheet1.getRange(i,4).getValue();
var HM=sheet1.getRange(i,5).getValue();
var Location=sheet1.getRange(i,6).getValue();
var message = sheet2.getRange(2,2).getValue();

message=message.replace("<Name>",Name).replace("<Title>",Title).replace("<Level>",Level).replace("<HM>",HM).replace("<Location>",Location);
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);}

}
```

Since I'm still learning, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to change. I have tried referencing others who have asked similar questions, but I end up getting lost trying to amend my script based on theirs. Any help for this beginner is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a loop and replace your getValue()'s with

```
values = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();//now the data is in a flattened array ie column1 is values[0], column2 is values[1]
```